# Здравствуйте. Вопрос такой - как изменить значения переменной в коде с помощью выбора в Dropdown [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 3 сложности. Необходимо что бы при изменении пользователем настройки в Dropdown, менялось две переменных в скрипте на другой сцене.

[image: Сложность]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator
{
   public int Width = 30;
   public int Height = 30;
}
```

То есть условно Лёгко = Width = 15 / Heigth = 15
Я в программировании новичок, поэтому не судите строго.

Comment: сохраняй настройку в playerPrefs? Сделать обьект с настройками и не выгружать его при переходе на другую сцену?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Я уже разобрался)